# Database modeling for defining and processing realtime sports events

Tags: database, database-design, real-time, dsl

I am trying to store and process sports events in realtime and want to create an optimal system as this will process 100s of events per second. The system will store the events before a sports match and then process them in real-time or at end of a half/session/match.

In my system, every `Event` is broken down into following components

- `WHO` whom is the event related to. A team, player, refree,
  spectators, etc
- `WHAT`  what is the event (goal, pass, save, etc)
- `WHEN`  time details of the event
- `HOWMUCH` how is the event value defined
- `TYPE` defines when should it be checked - `INDIVIDUAL` : realtime,
  `AGGREGATE` : end of `WHEN`

Here are some examples for soccer

```
1. No goals scored in 2nd Half
TEAM: *, WHAT: __GOAL, WHEN: __HALF_2, HOWMUCH: 0, TYPE: AGGREGATE 
{
    "who" : {"team":*},     
    "what" : "__GOAL",
    "when" : "__HALF_2"
    "howMuch" : {"value":0, "type" :"exact"},
    "type" : "AGGREGATE"
}


2. Either keeper to complete 3 or more punches
PLAYER: (p1 v p2), WHAT: __PUNCH, WHEN: __MATCH, HOWMUCH: 3+, TYPE: INDIVIDUAL
{
    "who" : {"player":{"or":["p1","p2"]}},  
    "what" : "__PUNCH",
    "when" : "__MATCH"
    "howMuch" : {"value":2, "type":"more"},
    "type" : "AGGREGATE"
}

3. Coutinho to score a goal before 65th min
PLAYER: p3, WHAT: __GOAL, WHEN: <65, TYPE: INDIVIDUAL
{
    "who" : {"player":"p3"},    
    "what" : "__GOAL",
    "when" : {"value" : 65, "type" : "before"}
    "type" : "INDIVIDUAL"
}


4. Henderson to play highest number of passes
PLAYER : p4, WHAT: __PASS, WHEN: __MATCH, HOWMUCH: __MAX, TYPE: AGGREGATE
{
    "who" : {"player":"p4"},    
    "what" : "__PASS",
    "when" : "__MATCH",
    "howMuch": "__MAX"    // this is a key word which will be handled accordingly on the application
    "type" : "AGGREGATE"
}

5. Liverpool to have more possession than everton
TEAM: (t1 > t2), WHAT: __POSSESSION, WHEN: __MATCH, TYPE: AGGREGATE      
{
    "who" : {"team":{"compare":["t1","t2"],"winner":"t2"}},     
    "what" : "__POSSESSION",
    "when" : "__MATCH"
    "type" : "AGGREGATE"
}
```

All `AGGREGATE` events will be checked when the state of the match changes. e.g. IInd half ---> MATCH_END

All `INDIVIDUAL` events will be checked for in real-time (as soon as a new event is received). This works on web hook.

E.g. A goal is scored in the 58th minute. 
Event received by system - `{"type":"goal","player":"_henderson_", "minute":58}`

The system would now run a  "find" where `("type" == "INDIVIDUAL" && "what" == "__GOAL")` and compare all the events found.

Later on, I would like to provide an admin functionality for writing sentences which can be parsed into this structure. What I want to know is if I am working in the right direction or do I need to start thinking in a different way.

Comment: Is there a reason you're sending aggregate events in real time? Wouldn't it be more efficient to send individual events only and perform aggregations on the server?

Comment: @RohanC - the events are provided by an external API. They are a stream of events happening in the match.

Comment: 1. Don't use the same word for the different notions of an "event" in the sense of a registered thing of interest vs "event" in the sense of raw real-time input. 2. First make a straightforward design re matches, then extend/modify re raw-events, then registered-events, then re optimizing evaluation of only certain registered-events on the basis of raw-events. 3. "Type" is determined by what part(s) of the current state a registered-event (and the query for it) is a function of. Look ahead to automating that determination based on what query you actually write/generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choices are probably between Spark and Dataflow. Here's a nice [white paper comparing the two](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/blog/dataflow-beam-and-spark-comparison) that actually uses a similar use case to yours (large scale mobile game user scoring in real time). Good luck, seems like a cool project (looks like an online bookmaking implementation?).